# Enterprise Architect Oracle long field column properties

Tags: oracle, sequence, enterprise-architect, datamodel

I have a little problem with Enterprise Architect by Sparx System. 
Im trying to model database schema for Oracle. I created table with primary key with data type  long. But when im trying to modify column properties (set AutoNum = true) I see empty properties. I read documentation of EA and saw that I need to setup this property to generate sequence syntax.

When I change data type to number, or switch database to mysql (for example) everything is alright, there are properties so Im able to modify AutoNum value.

Did you had similar problem and found solution ? or maybe im doing something wrong.

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's becouse Oracle use sequence instead of autoincrement option. I've checked it and I think you have to use NUMBER column type and then set AutoNum property (you have to select Generate Sequences in options to get proper DDL code too). Instead of LONG data type you can set PRECISION and SCALE options on NUMBER type ie NUMBER(8) mean you can have 8 digits number and it can be set up to 38, so if you don't want to store info about every star in the universe will be enought for your scenario :)